# Logically Consistent URLs with Complex/Nested Routes for nested data-driven menus?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, menu, routes

I am wondering how people handle nested/complex routes for an application when using a data-driven menu structure?

I've got two classes for my data driven menus:

```
 public class List : Entity
{
    public virtual ICollection<ListItem> ListItems { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public ListType ListType { get; set; }

    public string UlTagCssClass { get; set; }
    public string UlTagCssID { get; set; }
}

 public class ListItem : Entity
{
    public virtual List List { get; set; }
    public virtual ListItem ParentItem { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ListItem> ChildItems { get; set; }

    public int SortOrder { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Controller { get; set; }
    public string Action { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

I then have a recursive function that spits out any List into a nested `ul` tags (which is used as a menu). As it stands right now the `ListItem` can have a URL via straight up full URL, provide a controller and action, or not be a link at all.

However, I am running into a problem in that the URLs don't match the hierarchy of the menu, which is pretty common practice and most people would expect.

So for example I have a menu hierarchy such as:

- About
- Contact

  - Departments

    - Human Resources
    - Sales

So right now my top level item `Contact` has `.Controller = "Contact"`. It's child item `Departments` has `.Controller = "Content", .Action = "Departments"`. It's link as you would expect goes to www.domain.com/Contact/Departments. But my third level item `Sales` now has `.Controller = "Departments, .Action = "Sales"`. This makes the link www.domain.com/Departments/Sales, which doesn't make sense in the hierarchy of the menu.

What is a good approach to store the proper URL and generate the routes to support that (I can change the ListItem class if necessary)? Also how would one structure their views/controllers in such a scenario? I am not sure how to continue with the increasing depth as I've only ever really developed MVC apps where I hard-coded routes or just used the default controller/action route, *but now I am trying to make it more data-driven*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following route and add it before your default routes:

Dynamically map these on application launch by pulling in your menu list and iterating down through the list.
I would prefer not to dynamically map these unless they change on the fly
As you need supporting files (views, etc) that you likely don't create dynamically

```
 routes.MapRoute("Contact", "Contact/{action}", 
                 new { controller = "Contact"});
 routes.MapRoute("Departments", "Contact/Departments/{action}", 
                 new { controller = "Departments"});
```

Comment: Just so I understand this correctly, I would need to basically point two actions to the same view then wouldn't I? Because the Departments action on the Contact controller, would point to the same page as the Index action on the Departments controller? 

How would you generate those routes dynamically?

Comment: Good call, I should give it no default action or else it would take this route when it shouldn't, I'll update my answer a bit